# TypeScript doesn't know that component gets required prop from HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, high-order-component

I'm wrapping export of my component with HOC which adds prop to it, but TypeScript doesn't see that this prop (which is required) was already added by HOC.

Component:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { withText } from "../hoc";

interface Props {
  text: string;
}

function TestComponent({ text }: Props) {
  return <div>{text}</div>;
}

export default withText(TestComponent);
```

HOC:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { useContext, ReactElement, ComponentType } from "react";
import { TextContext } from "../contexts";

const withText = <P extends object>(
  Component: ComponentType<P>
): ((props: P) => ReactElement) => props => (
  <Component text={useContext(TextContext).value} {...props} />
);

export default withText;
```

Context:

```js
import { createContext } from "react";

const TextContext = createContext<{ value: string }>({
  value: ""
});

export default TextContext;
```

App:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { TextContext } from "./contexts";
import { TestComponent } from "./components";

function App() {
  return (
    <TextContext.Provider value={{ value: "Lorem ipsum" }}>
      <TestComponent /> /* TS throws an error here */
    </TextContext.Provider>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Error which throws TS:
`Property 'text' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Props'`

Expected behavior: TypeScript knows that 'text' prop was already added by withText HOC

Link to codesandbox -> [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-https-wf59t?fontsize=12)

Comment: [check this](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-router/index.d.ts). you should create some omit type what will exlude some properties...  check the last withRouter function type declatarion. withRouter is exactly what you are doing

Comment: @JurajKocan I've tried a solution which you propose using `Omit<P, "text">` but it still doesn't work. I've tried to approach it on a lot of different levels but I can't find a solution. Do you have any idea how can I solve it? [link to codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-river-mc9s5?fontsize=12)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work for you

```
 type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;
 interface InterfaceToOmit {
   text: string;
 }

    const withText = <P extends InterfaceToOmit>(Component: React.ComponentType<P>): React.ComponentClass<Omit<P, keyof InterfaceToOmit>> => {
      // tslint:disable-next-line:max-classes-per-file
      class MyHocClass extends React.Component<Omit<P, keyof InterfaceToOmit>> {
        public render() {
          return <Component text={'what ever your HOC component waht to pass here'} {...this.props as P} />;
        }
      }

      return MyHocClass;
    };

export default withText
```

you need to return another component what will have omitted props. so when you will use withText it will be component with only these props what you dont want to pass in HOC component. in this example its InterfaceToOmit

so your component will still have all the props

```
type propsToMyComponent = {
  anything: string;
} & InterfaceToOmit;

const testComponent = (props: propsToMyComponent) => {
  return <div>asd</div>;
};
```

then use it like

```
 const WithTextComponent = withText<propsToMyComponent>(testComponent);
```

now ou can call it only with one prop

```
<WithTextComponent anything={''} />; // no error
```

Comment: ts can infer type so you dont really need to use generic type here: const WithTextComponent = withText(testComponent);... still will work

Comment: and ofc you dont need to return class. if you want to have just stateless componenet. it depends what will your HOC component do...